# JQuery ListView New Item Flash

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make AJAX additions to a JQuery listview flash yellow, but I can't seem to get it working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/zFybm/

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery page,

**"width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)"** http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You could look into jQuery.Color(), or use one of these other solutions:

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/

Comment: This code works on another page: `$(".answerbox").animate({backgroundColor: "#F00"}).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFF"});`

Comment: Make sure you are importing all the required javascript, including the jQuery color if applicable. The fiddle works with height but not with background-color, which goes inline with what that jQuery page said since jQuery color is not included in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

use this code.. it works fine

```
function newitem(){
var text='<li><p>new</p></li>';
var elem=$(text);
elem.css("background", "#FFA");
$('#list').prepend(elem);
$('#list').listview("refresh");
elem.animate({backgroundColor: "#EEE"});
}
newitem();​
```